# Hostel accommodation in China

Tags: china, accommodation, study, family

I am from Pakistan and I am travelling with my 8-year-old son to China to study for a year in Chongqing technology and business university. Could anyone tell me how to look for family accommodation in China?

I would highly appreciate if someone could help me by sending websites where I could look for accommodation. Many thanks!

Comment: Have you asked your university about campus housing?

Comment: Questions about long-term visits, such as studying, are off-topic here but can be asked on [expatriates.se]. You can click the "flag" link below your question to ask the moderators to move it but, since it's not been answered yet, it's easier to just delete it here and repost.